# How can I get all coordinates between two points polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet, leaflet.draw

How can or i found all coordinates between two points on poly line. 
I doesn't need distance or only mid point.

Let suppose  I have two points

1. Point A (left) lat: 39.091868 long: -9.263187
2. Point B (right) lat: 39.089815 long: -9.261857

Point A to B get all coordinates lies on line below screenshot

[image]

Comment: You're aware that there is an infinite amount of points in-between two points?

Comment: What do you mean by "all coordinates"? Do you have some data you want to validate against these two points? Also, what have you tried to do to solve this problem?

Comment: @obscure  we need all  those coordinates  that exists  on our poly line between two vertex ...

Comment: @SebastianGaweda no we dont have coordinates .. we need google map coordinates that exists on our poly line between two vertex

Comment: @RafiUllahPatel I just wanted to say that you need to limit the number of points because in theory it's infinite. Since you're talking about a polyline you want to get full pixel integer values of those points? Maybe you should add the screenshot you're referring to.

Comment: @obscure https://prnt.sc/o3v7ej only line draw get coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

We get distance between two point and check if distance is under 3 meters or any value. After the result return true we call recursive function.
    function getTwoPointMidCoord($coordinates) {

```
$num_coords = count($coordinates);

$sumY = 0;
$sumZ = 0;
$LATIDX = 0;
$LNGIDX = 1;
$sumX = 0;
$sumY = 0;
$sumZ = 0;

foreach ($coordinates as $key => $value) {
$lat = deg2rad($value[0]);
$lng = deg2rad($value[1]);
$sumX += cos($lat) * cos($lng);
$sumY += cos($lat) * sin($lng);
$sumZ += sin($lat);
}

$avgX = $sumX / 2;
$avgY = $sumY / 2;
$avgZ = $sumZ / 2;

$lng = atan2($avgY, $avgX);
$hyp = sqrt($avgX * $avgX + $avgY * $avgY);
$lat = atan2($avgZ, $hyp);
return ([rad2deg($lat), rad2deg($lng)]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comments it's impossible to get all points laying on a line because the number is infinite.

You can however return a fixed amount of points. This number highly depends on the level of precision you want to achieve though.

```js
Point = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
var pointA = new Point(39.091868, -9.263187);
var pointB = new Point(39.089815, -9.261857);

var numberOfPoints = 20;
var points = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++) {
  points.push(new Point((Math.abs(pointA.x - pointB.x) / 10) * i + pointB.y, (Math.abs(pointA.y - pointB.y) / numberOfPoints) * i + pointB.y));
}

console.log(points);
```

Comment: missing lat in your array x and y show both long values 0: Point
x: -9.261857
y: -9.261857
__proto__: Object
1: Point
x: -9.261790499999998
y: -9.261790499999998
__proto__: Object
2: Point

Comment: Oh sorry, a little type inside the Point definition. I fixed the example above!

Comment: Please be aware that this is valid for euclidean geometry on a plane, but not for geodetic calculations - a geodetic solution would involve calculating the arc of the great circle encompassing both points.

Comment: For me it also shows x and y as long values, example: 'Point { x: -9.261857, y:  -9.261790499999998}. 
How can I solve this so that latitude shows value as x?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. We get distance between two point and check if distance is under 3 meters or any value. After the result return true we call recursive function. PHP code.

```
global $array;
$array = array();

function recurCollectCoords($coords) {
global $array;
$coords = array(
    array(24.925274, 67.096988),
    array(24.924872, 67.097367),
    array(24.924946, 67.097481)
);
foreach ($coords as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($coords[$key + 1])) {
$distance = distance($value[0], $value[1], $coords[$key + 1][0], $coords[$key + 1] 
[1], "M");
if ($distance > 3) { //Using each coordinate collect 3 meter distance 
$coordinates = array(array($value[0], $value[1]), array($coords[$key + 1][0], 
$coords[$key + 1][1]));
$midpoint = getTwoPointMidCoord($coordinates);
$newCoord[] = array(array($value[0], $value[1]), array($midpoint[0], 
$midpoint[1]), array($coords[$key + 1][0], $coords[$key + 1][1]));
recurCollectCoords(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $newCoord));
} else {
array_push($array, array((string) $value[0], (string) $value[1]));
        }
    }
array_push($array, array((string) $value[0], (string) $value[1]));
}
$uniqueCoords = array_values(array_map("unserialize", 
array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array))));
return $uniqueCoords;
}

function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
if (($lat1 == $lat2) && ($lon1 == $lon2)) {
    return 0;
} else {
    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * 
cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);

    if ($unit == "K") {
        return ($miles * 1.609344);
    } else if ($unit == "N") {
        return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else if ($unit == "M") {
        return ($miles * 1.609344) * 1000;
    } else {
        return $miles;
    }
}
```

}

```
function getTwoPointMidCoord($coordinates) {

$num_coords = count($coordinates);

$sumY = 0;
$sumZ = 0;
$LATIDX = 0;
$LNGIDX = 1;
$sumX = 0;
$sumY = 0;
$sumZ = 0;

foreach ($coordinates as $key => $value) {
    $lat = deg2rad($value[0]);
    $lng = deg2rad($value[1]);
    $sumX += cos($lat) * cos($lng);
    $sumY += cos($lat) * sin($lng);
    $sumZ += sin($lat);
}

$avgX = $sumX / 2;
$avgY = $sumY / 2;
$avgZ = $sumZ / 2;

$lng = atan2($avgY, $avgX);
$hyp = sqrt($avgX * $avgX + $avgY * $avgY);
$lat = atan2($avgZ, $hyp);
return ([rad2deg($lat), rad2deg($lng)]);
}
```